# Paint brush swipe background image is not centered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the Questions page (https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions) the paint brush swipe underneath the number of answers for a question is not centered.  It is too far to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment